# Changing config values from within a hook

Tags: juju

I am writing a charm for my product and trying to set/unset a config.yaml parameter from within a hook.
Can anyone please tell me, how it can be done .I am writing charm in bash scripts

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change charm config parameters from within a hook, sorry.